# Unity: Ignoring 2D collisions based on contexts like trajectory or speed

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I went through the documentation and I can find no way to achieve the simplest contact management using the built-in physics engine.

I have a situation where 2D collisions should be ignored when for example 2 objects are traveling in similar directions at similar speed (Basically when the distance of their velocity vectors subtraction is too short)...

These object are in layers which define the other types of objects they should collide with in normal circumstances. The number of objects intersecting (and not colliding) can increase arbitrarily. So changing layers is not a viable option.

Using regular box2d I would use the `b2ContactListener.PreSolve` to filter the objects based on their masks **and additional parameters** depending on the masks. What is the equivalent with Unity's 2D API?

Comment: Have you looked up the methods of OnCollision___2D and OnTrigger___2D?? You could change the collision layer for different directions and collisions will automatically happen.

Comment: @Savlon : To my understanding OnCollision2D is triggered after collision resolution... Am I wrong? If not, is there a way to cancel the result when it is triggered? I already use layers for 4 different types of objects and 4 different players. I have an arbitrary number of objects and unless My understanding of layers is wrong I can't see how what you suggest could be achieved with layers.

Comment: What happens if you disable the corresponding `Rigidbody` components in `OnCollisionEnter2D()`? Does it give the results you are looking for?

Comment: @AldourCheng `rigidbody2D.active = false` makes objects simply inactive. `coll.rigidbody.collisionDetectionMode = CollisionDetectionMode2D.None` produces no visible effect. If you meant deactivating the colliders then no. Because then the objects with disabled colliders will not collide with other mutually excluded objects moving the other way, or walls, or other objects they should hit. Is there a way to cancel a collision in `OnCollisionEnter2D`?

Comment: @Coyote Do you mean you want to temporarily disable the object from being affected by the built in physics engine? According to the [manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html), `Rigidbody` is responsible for this. So what if you [take it out from physics control](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-isKinematic.html)?

Comment: @AldourCheng No I mean I want an object to temporarily not collide with other objects going in a very similar direction at similar speed. I want to give the opportunity to some types of objects which normally collide to not collide if the distance of the relativeVelocity (`coll.relativeVelocity.magnitude`) is small enough. This is a very simple thing to do with any physics engine since the 90's. And I struggle to get this done with Unity.

Comment: @Coyote AFAIK, there are no methods exposed which provide the exact functionality. The closest way I can think of to mimic what you did with Box2D is what @Savlon suggested: using `OnCollision_2D` or `OnTrigger_2D` to reset the velocities of objects to their previous values before collisions.

Comment: @AldourCheng Do you think this will not interfere with other collisions which might happen in the same cycle? like collisions with walls and other objects?

Comment: Yes it does interfere. Suggestions from @Leoson seems to be the only way left. It will be great if anyone can enlighten me with some more sophisticated methods to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I'm aware off to change collision behavior during runtime, is to disable collisions between two layers or between two colliders.

If your objects are already on different layers, you can disable (and enable) collisions between them via [`Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision.html).

If you don't want to disable whole layers, you can specify two colliders that should ignore each other with [`Physics2D.IgnoreCollision()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.IgnoreCollision.html)

Since there is no method called *before* the collision happens, you either need to check yourself which objects could collide and enable or disable the collision or use `OnCollisionEnter2D()` and disable the collision afterwards. For the second way you would need to store the velocities before the collision and set them again after the collision happened.

To add some kind of pre-check, you can add a larger second collider around the object and set it as trigger. During `OnTriggerEnter2D()` you can check if the actual collision should happen.

Comment: So far I use Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(). But some objects have multiple colliders and the process even if automated is not very interesting as then I have to add special triggers to check if the objects are currently ignoring each other if yes remove them once they crossed... and then... How do you un-ignore collisions?

Comment: @Coyote to re-enable collisions use the third parameter: `IgnoreCollision(collider1, collider2, false)`

Comment: This will not work either. When objects collide putting the velocity back after the collision will also cancel the changes in velocity which happened with other objects, and the positions are also wrong.

Comment: @Coyote if they are wrong, you obviously set them wrong. As already stated in the answer, you need to save their values before the collision happens. Maybe it's easier to write your own collision behavior and just use the trigger function provided by Unity. Without knowing more about your project, it's impossible to say what  kind of approach might be the best.

Comment: When other components add forces and update velocity then the cached values are not updated. Basically I have to make all other components aware of the caching system for this workaround to start working... Objects which don't require the workaround keep working as intended, objects with the workaround and without other components/objects changing their forces are not behaving properly. I'm still baffled by the absence of a pre-solver callback in unity...